# How do I start Rainmeter before or during logging into Windows 11

Tags: windows, widget, startup, windows-11, rainmeter

I want to know if there is any possibility that Rainmeter will start with the system once you log in, the wigets will appear on the screen.I tried with modifying the registry but it didn't work

What I want is more precisely that there is no delay of a few seconds